# 32-bit code runs on 64-bit linux machine

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, 32bit-64bit

My linux is 64 bit Red Hat 6.5. GCC is 4.4.7. I have a code originally running on 32 bit machine, which means, there are a lot of conversion from a pointer to a int. When I make, I get `error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision`. I know that is because in 64-bit OS pointer type is 8 bytes.

I don't want to fix all of this one by one because there are too many, so I add `-m32` flag in the makefile CFLGAS, which make 32 bit code run on a compiler configured for 64-bit object by default.

Good thing is this compiling error is gone. However, compiler gives me this `main.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format`. Seems like this is still some compatible issue between 32-bit and 64-bit. Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

This is part of my makefile.common used for gmake:

```
CFLAGS = -m32 -g -Wall -Wshadow $(INCPATH) $(DEFINES) $(HOST) -DCHANGED 
LDFLAGS = -m32

CPP= gcc -E -m32
CC = g++
LD = g++
AS = as --32
.......
S_OFILES = switch.o

OFILES = $(C_OFILES) $(S_OFILES)

$(PROGRAM): $(OFILES)
    $(LD) $(OFILES) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM)

$(C_OFILES): %.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

Comment: amongst other things, unless your source files are actually written using the C++ language (classes, iterators, STL calls, etc etc) then you should use gcc instead of g++.   Otherwise all the compiler calls should be g++.    Note: the make file is missing certain items, like the local header file dependencies for each source file.   the linker takes/processes parameters in the order given.. so <tab>$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OFILES) -Llibrarypath -llibrrayshortnames -o $(PROGRAM)  the compile step should be something like: %.o:%.c then <tab>$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I$(INCPATH)

Comment: is there a rule for compiling the *.s files?

Comment: your code is already bad at the beginning. Leaving it as-is would make future maintenance a horrible pain. Pointers should not be stored as ints, and in cases needed should always be stored in `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not enter your linker (g ++) that the assembly code are 32bit instructions.

try:

```
CPP= gcc -E -m32
CC = g++ -m32
LD = g++ 
AS = as --32
```

Comment: If you mean adding to LD = g++ -m elf_i386, then it gave me this "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format"

Comment: If you know your answer is wrong, delete it rather than editing to apologise for your mistake